# Django urls configuration

Tags: django, django-urls, django-url-reverse

I have an example website using django. I have 2 link "about" and "blog".  When I click "blog" it become localhost/blog and nothing problem, but when I click "blog" once more it become localhost/blog/blog and error happen. What's the solution?

Comment: Please post your `urls.py`.

Comment: Also the part of the template with the "blog" link ...

Comment: Your link tag is probably `<a href="blog">` which just adds 'blog' to the current URL, hence you get /blog/blog/. You need to include a forward slash before it: `<a href="/blog">`